# Cant make post request to my server on openshift

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, openshift

Description:
Get requests works fine. Example from python interpretator:

> > > r = requests.get("http://openshift-XXXXXXXXX/get_all_posts")
> > >
> > > r.text
> > >
> > > '{"posts":[]}'

But the problem is to make the post requests:
Ill give an example:

> > > r = requests.post("http://openshift-XXXXXXXX/create_user", json={"username":"user","nickname":"nick", "password":"pass"})
> > >
> > > r.text
> > >
> > > '\n500 Internal Server Error\n
> > >
> > > ## Internal Server Error
> > >
> > > \n
> > >
> > > The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
> > >
> > > \n'

Any help would be appreciated.

setup.py

```
    from setuptools import setup

setup(name='YourAppName',
      version='1.0',
      description='OpenShift App',
      author='Ludvig Westerdahl',
      author_email='example@example.com',
      url='http://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      install_requires=['Flask','Flask-SQLAlchemy>=2.1',           "sqlalchemy>=1.0.11"],
     )
```

wsgi.py

```
        #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
from magdb import app as application

virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR','.'), 'virtenv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
    httpd = make_server('localhost', 5002, application)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

magdb.py

```
        from flask import Flask, json, jsonify, request, g
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import class_mapper
import os
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from functools import wraps
from itsdangerous import (TimedJSONWebSignatureSerializer
                          as Serializer, BadSignature, SignatureExpired)
from sqlalchemy import update

# --------------------------
# --- App creation START ---
# --------------------------
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Will Will Smith smith? Yes... Will Smith will smith'

if "OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL" in os.environ:
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]=os.environ['OPENSHIFT_POSTGRESQL_DB_URL']

else:
    app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"]="sqlite:////tmp/testmagdb.db"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)





# --------------------------
# --- App creation END -----
# --------------------------

friends_table = db.Table("friends_table",
db.Column("user_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
db.Column("friend_id", db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"), primary_key=True),
                   db.PrimaryKeyConstraint("user_id", "friend_id"))


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # --- Creation of Account requirments ---
    username = db.Column(db.String(25))
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(25))
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))

    # --- Creation of profile ---
    description_column = db.Column(db.String(255))
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)

    #friends = db.relationship("User",  backref=db.backref("users", lazy="dynamic"), secondary=friends_table)
    my_friends = db.relationship('User',
                              secondary=friends_table,
                              primaryjoin=(friends_table.c.user_id == id),
                              secondaryjoin=(friends_table.c.friend_id == id),
                              backref=db.backref("friends_of_me", lazy='dynamic'),
                              lazy='dynamic')


    liked_posts = []
    dissliked_posts = []

    token = db.Column(db.Text)

    def __init__(self, username, nickname, password):
        self.username = username
        self.nickname = nickname
        self.password = generate_password_hash(password)
        self.rating = 0


    def reset_token(self):
        self.token = None

    def set_token(self, token):
        self.token = token

    def get_token(self):
        return self.token

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password, password)

    def generate_auth_token(self, experation=6000):
        s = Serializer(app.config['SECRET_KEY'], expires_in=experation)
        return s.dumps({'id':self.id})

    # --- Profile management ---

    def get_rating(self):
        return self.rating

    def mod_rating(self, rating):
        self.rating += rating



    def undo_rating(self, id):
        self.rating = 0
        """
        if id in self.dissliked_post_list:
            self.rating += 1
            self.dissliked_post_list.remove(id)
        if id in self.liked_post_list:
            self.rating -= 1
            self.liked_post_list.remove(id)
        """




    def get_description(self):
        return self.description

    def set_description(self, description):
        self.description_column = description

    def get_description(self):
        return self.description_column

    def to_json(self):
        s = {"nickname":self.nickname, "description":self.description_column, "rating":self.rating}
        return json.dumps(s)
        #return json.dumps(dict(username=self.username))

    def to_dict(self):
        s = {"nickname":self.nickname, "description":self.description_column, "rating":self.rating}
        return s

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    title = db.Column(db.String(50))
    game = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.String(255))
    comment = db.Column(db.String(255))


    owner = db.relationship('User', backref=db.backref('posts', lazy='dynamic'))
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


    def __init__(self, title, game, description, owner):
        self.title = title
        self.game = game
        self.description = description
        self.owner = owner
        self.comment = ""

    def add_comment(self, comment):
        self.comment = self.comment + comment
    def to_json(self):
        # username va nickname förut
        s = {"title": self.title, "game":self.game, "description":self.description, "owner": self.owner.username, "comments":self.comment}
        return json.dumps(s)

    def to_dict(self):
        # username va nickname förut
        s = {"title": self.title, "game":self.game, "description":self.description, "owner": self.owner.username, "comments":self.comment}
        return s


@app.route('/set_description', methods=['POST'])
def set_description():
    input = request.get_json()
    user_id = input['user_id']
    description = input['description']
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    user.set_description(description)
    commit_db()
    return "Description set", 200


@app.route('/remove_friend', methods=['POST'])
def remove_friend():
    input = request.get_json()
    user_id = input['user_id']
    friend_username = input['friend_username']
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    friend = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == friend_username).first()
    try:
        user.my_friends.remove(friend)
        commit_db()
    except:
        return "Not friend", 400

    return "Sucess removed friend", 200

@app.route('/add_friend', methods=['POST'])
def add_friend():
    input = request.get_json()
    user_id = input['user_id']
    friend_username = input['friend_username']
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    friend = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == friend_username).first()
    try:
        user.my_friends.append(friend)
        commit_db()
    except:
        return "Already friend", 400

    return "Sucess added friend", 200

@app.route('/get_all_friends/<int:user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_friends(user_id):
    list_of_friends = []
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()
    for friend in user.my_friends:
        list_of_friends.append(friend.to_dict())


    return json.dumps({"friends": list_of_friends})

@app.route('/get_friend/<username>', methods=['GET'])
def get_friend(username):
    friend = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()
    return friend.to_json()

@app.route('/get_rating/<user_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_rating(user_id):
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()

    return str(user.rating), 200



@app.route('/comment', methods=['POST'])
def comment():
    input = request.get_json()
    comment = input['comment']
    post_id = input['post_id']
    post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == post_id).first()
    post.add_comment(comment + "\n")
    commit_db()
    return "comment:" + comment + "added", 200


@app.route('/modify_rating', methods=['POST'])
def modify_rating():
    input = request.get_json()
    rating = input['rating']

    # This is the post that they user has clicked like on
    post_id = input['post_id']
    post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == post_id).first()

    # The input user-id is the one that is liking/dissliking something
    user_id = input['user_id']
    user = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == user_id).first()

    # User liked the post
    print("HERE")
    if rating == 1:
        print("HERE1")
        if post_id in user.dissliked_posts:
            user.liked_posts.append(post_id)
            user.dissliked_posts.remove(post_id)
            post.owner.mod_rating(2)
            print("HERE2")
        elif not post_id in user.liked_posts:
            user.liked_posts.append(post_id)
            post.owner.mod_rating(1)
            print("HERE3")
    elif rating == -1:
        print("HERE4")
        if post_id in user.liked_posts:
            user.dissliked_posts.append(post_id)
            user.liked_posts.remove(post_id)
            post.owner.mod_rating(-2)
            print("HERE5")

        elif not post_id in user.dissliked_posts:
            user.dissliked_posts.append(post_id)
            post.owner.mod_rating(-1)
            print("HERE6")
    elif rating == 0:
        print("HERE7")
        if post_id in user.liked_posts:
            user.liked_posts.remove(post_id)
            post.owner.mod_rating(-1)
            print("HERE8")
        elif post_id in user.dissliked_posts:
            user.dissliked_posts.remove(post_id)
            post.owner.mod_rating(1)
            print("HERE9")

    print(str(post.owner.rating))
    db.session.commit()
    print(str(post.owner.rating))


    return "DONE", 200

@app.route('/get_post/<int:post_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_post(post_id):
    try:
        post = db.session.query(Post).filter(Post.id == post_id).first()
        return post.to_json(), 200
    except:
        return "Post doesnt exist", 400
    #if not post == None:
     #   return post.to_json(), 200



@app.route('/get_all_posts', methods=['GET'])
def get_all_posts():
    list_of_posts = []
    for post in db.session.query(Post).all():
        list_of_posts.append(post.to_dict())

    return json.dumps({"posts": list_of_posts})


@app.route('/post', methods=['POST'])
def create_post():
    input = request.get_json()
    title = input['title']
    game = input['game']
    description = input['description']
    owner_id = input['owner_id']
    owner = db.session.query(User).filter(User.id == owner_id).first()

    post = Post(title, game, description, owner)
    db.session.add(post)
    commit_db()
    return "Post created", 200



@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():
    input = request.get_json()
    username = input['username']
    password = input['password']
    user_trying_to_login = db.session.query(User).filter(User.username == username).first()

    if user_trying_to_login == None:
        print("Inside == none")
        return "Username + password not matching", 400
    print("----------BEFORE CHECK PASS------")
    if user_trying_to_login.check_password(password):
        print("----------INSIDE CHECK PASS------")
        # return id so we know which one is logged in during the session from the app
        return json.dumps({"id":user_trying_to_login.id}), 200
    else:
        print("----------INSIDE ELSE CHECK PASS------")
        return "Username(else) + password not matching", 400



@app.route('/create_user', methods=['POST'])
def create_user():
    input = request.get_json()
    new_user = User(input['username'], input['nickname'], input['password'])
    db.session.add(new_user)
    commit_db()
    return "user added", 200

# ---------------------------------
# ----- Db START ------------------
# ---------------------------------



def serialize(model):
    columns = [c.key for c in class_mapper(model.__class__).columns] # Create a list from the columns.

    return dict((c, getattr(model, c)) for c in columns) # Return a dictionary containing the columns.


def reset_db():
    try:
        db.drop_all()
        db.session.commit()
    except: #TEST
        db.session.rollback() #TEST


def commit_db():
    db.session.commit()


def init_db():
    db.create_all()

# ---------------------------------
# ----- Db END --------------------
# ---------------------------------




db.create_all()
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "/magdb"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True
    app.run(debug=True, port=5002)
```

Basically, everything works fine on the local to the sqllite database. But then deploying to openshift, post requests gives the Internal Server Error

Comment: Have you tried to debug the function create_user() already?

Answer (score 0):

First things first: Do not use 'input' as the variable name. this is the replacement of 'input_raw' since python 3.

Now your problem:
I had similar problems using requests 2.2.1 locally.
Then I removed python-requests using apt-get remove and **installed requests 2.9.1 using pip**.

Maybe on the openshift servers there is a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

What happened here was that the password which i "hashed" on the openshift server became to big for the Column that it was suppose to be stored in. So therefore the internal server error arrised.

**So sum it up**: If someone has a similar problem. Even though it might work on the sqllite server, make sure that it works on the openshift server by checking the log files. A very nice command i used to find out that the column couldnt store the password was: **rhc tail -o "-n 20" -a**